# Using a boost converter as a laser driver for high power diode

Tags: batteries, diodes, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I want to power this [7W 450nm Laser Diode](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P8L792J) (*Nichia NUBM44*) using a [3.7V 3.3Ah Li-ion Battery](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pkcell/ICR18650-3350-F/11629973) (*ICR18650-3350-F*). The power required by the laser diode is **5V@4A**. Most laser drivers I could find qualified for this type of diode (For example, the [ACS4500BU](https://sites.google.com/site/dtrslasershop/home/laser-drivers/acs4500bu-4-5a-buck)) required a power supply of 6V.

I could use a boost converter in addition to this driver, however I am in a space-constrained project and feel it would be much more convenient if the boost converter could also act as a driver by giving back a constant current.

I managed to find a [boost converter](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1709.pdf) (*MAX1709*) which could take an input anywhere from 0.7-5V and output either **3.3V/5.5V @ 4A**. This seems perfect, as my diode takes **5V@4A**, and from what I can tell the datasheets claim it has voltage as well as current regulation.

I've been drawing the connections in KiCad, and am somewhat confused with the *MAX1709* datasheet on how and what I am supposed to do with certain pins.

*This is where I need help*:

I want to know if the connections I have so far are correct, and if not what I would need to do to fix them. I also would like to know that even if I got the connections down perfectly, would this be a relatively safe system for powering a laser diode, or is there something more to a laser driver than just a voltage/current regulator?

With that said, here is my current setup in using the *MAX1709* to convert a 3.7V, 3.3Ah battery to a **5V@4A** power supply. Fair note, there is more to my setup than *just* the *MAX1709*, however I will only mention the connections that concern the *MAX1709*, as I am most unsure if that is correct (I'll leave a description of each of my connections below.)

[image: laser setup as of now]

- *PGND*: Connect all other PGND pins together, then to GND
- *LX*: Connect 2, 3, and 4 LX pins together, as well as Vin, and finally a set of two parallel 150uF capacitors for current stability and a 5A Schottky diode connected to OUT (the datasheet mentioned using an inductor for 'switching frequency', not sure if this matters however.)
- *FB*: PGND (to internally allow for the setting of voltage.)
- *GND*: Connect all other GND pins together, then to GND.
- *ONA*, *ONB*: Not Connected (Don't need functionality.)
- *CLK*: Not Connected (Or do I need an oscillation for my diode?)
- *3.3/5*: OUT (pull to high to indicate 5V output.)
- *SS/LIM*: Not Connected (Is this safe?)
- *REF*: Not Connected (Not really sure what it's used for.)
- *EP*: Not Connected (In the future I'll probably connect it to the ground plane or add a heatsink to dissipate the heat.)
- *OUT*: Connected to 3.3/5 pin, a 2ohm resistor for 'stability', and a diode to LX pin, and the anode of the laser diode.
- *Laser diode*: Connect anode to OUT pin, and cathode to GND.
- *Li-ion battery*: Connect GND to GND plane, and +3.7V to a pushbutton to turn the laser on/off, then inductor (?), and finally the LX pins

As I mentioned, this was only a list of the connections concerning the *MAX1709*, but if you see anything else wrong with my setup feel free to point it out.

Comment: Most high power laser diodes have a feedback photodetector.  You monitor it to maintain a fixed "brightness."  You use the feedback from the photodiode to regulate the current to the laser.  Laser intensity varies with current, but also with other things.  Also, a safe laser driver includes shutdown features to protect the diode at power on and off - and power failure.  Those protection circuits may be in that driver you dismissed, or you can implement them yourself - and take up more space on your board than a proper driver would occupy.

Comment: Test it thoroughly with a 1.2 ohm load resistor before letting it get anywhere near a laser diode. (And I'm assuming that laser diode has built-in driver electronics. It really won't like 5V otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

Well, sorry about that ;) pretty much everything in the schematic is wrong. Where is the inductor? And the input/output decoupling? C3/C4 will block output voltage. There should be an example schematic in the datasheet.

A synchronous converter (without diode) would offer better efficiency which should be important when using battery power.

Note that the input power of a boost converter is equal to output power plus losses, therefore input current will be:

\$ Iin = \frac{1}{Efficiency} Iout \frac{Vout}{Vin}  \$

With 90% efficiency, 4A 5V out, 3V in, this gives an input current of 7A. This is way above what a standard 18650 LiIon battery can provide so you will need a high current capable battery, as used in e-cigarettes for example.

If you used two lithium cells instead of one, you could use a buck converter, whose input current follows the same equation... but in this case Vin>Vout which means Iin will be much lower.

With 90% efficiency, 4A 5V out, 6V in, this gives an input current of 3.7A, much easier on the batteries. It also has higher efficiency due to less RI^2 losses. So, only use a boost if you absolutely want to use one cell to make it small.

You could use a boost LED driver chip, or a buck LED driver chip if you use 2 cells, which will regulate current. This would be mots convenient. You can use a voltage output DC-DC converter too but then it's wasteful to put a resistor in series with the laser diode. You can make a voltage output buck converter regulate current by using a current sense amp and a shunt resistor in series with the laser diode, and an opamp to amplify the voltage on it to make the desired current correspond to the feedback voltage on the DC-DC converter, but this requires some attention to frequency compensation.